# clarification using strdup() or strcpy()

Tags: c

i have a problem
this method works fine, it returns a struct with the right NaME value

```
prodotti creaProdotto(char *name, float price, prodotti next){
    prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(prodotti));
    p->name = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    p->name = strdup( name);
    p->price = price;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}
```

else this do not works,

```
prodotti creaProdotto(char *name, float price, prodotti next){
    prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(prodotti));
    p->name = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    p->price = price;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}
```

the problem in the second is: name does not contains the right value,
please explain ne why.

Comment: Post a complete example, including the pointer hiding typedef.

Comment: Yes, post the struct definition. Your first example should not need `malloc` *and* `strdup`, since that's what `strdup` does - you'll cause a memory leak because it won't be possible to `free` the pointer allocated by `p->name = malloc(...)`

Comment: This code is surely wrong in both cases: `prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(prodotti));`.  You want maybe  `prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`, supposing that `prodotti` is typedefed as a pointer type.

Comment: ...also the magic number `30` should be replaced by `strlen(name) + 1`

Comment: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: And **do not** `typedef` pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that `prodotti` is typedefed as a pointer type, you have a fundamental problem with this (in both cases):

```
    prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(prodotti));
```

You allocate only enough space for one pointer, not for the thing it points *to*.  As a result, you invoke undefined behavior when you assign to members of `*p` whose putative storage extends further from the the beginning of the object than the size of a pointer.

This kind of confusion is one good reason to avoid hiding pointer nature behind a typedef.  Having done so, however, you can avoid explicitly referencing the actual type behind the typedef like so:

```
    prodotti p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

This is a good pattern to adopt in any case, because it is resilient against changes in the pointed-to type.

Since you have undefined behavior in both cases, it's a bit pointless to speculate on what's actually happening, because *speculating* is all we can do from a language standpoint.  This is what "undefined" means.

Additionally, as others have observed, it is worse than pointless to `malloc()` memory for `p->name` and then overwrite the resulting pointer with the result of `strdup()`.  Not only do you then allocate more memory than you need, but you also leak the memory obtained via the `malloc()`.  It seems that `strdup()` by itself, without a preceding `malloc()`, would be a reasonable approach here.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have too many information to help you in details, but:

1. It seems that `prodotti` is of pointer type, so you didn't allocate memory for a full structure, only for a pointer. Use `malloc(sizeof *prodotti)`.
2. `strdup` allocated the memory and duplicate the c-string
3. `strcpy` just copy the content of the given c-string onto the memory given

It is then not useful to allocate memory if you use `strdup`.

You may have allocate not many memory in the second case, so that you encounter some kind of buffer overflow (depending on the string you used). Use the standard idiom: `p->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1); strcpy(p->name,name);`

You must correct point n°1 before anything else... Always verify if allocations are successful.